# Struts2 - FileUpload Max Size - When exceed limit "struts.multipart.maxSize" other fields are null

Tags: file-upload, struts2, upload, limit

Using struts2 (2.3.16.1) I configured the general limit of file upload in struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2621440" />
```

and I didn't configured any limit in my action

```
<action name="sendEmail" class="com.my.SendMail" method="executeSendEmail">
    <result name="error">/jsp/emailForm.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/jsp/emailOk.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/jsp/emailForm.jsp</result>        
</action>
```

When the upload limit is exceeded the execution flow return correctly to "input" jsp **but all the uploaded form fields are null**, so the form appears **empty**.

Any suggest to save the value of the form fields?

Comment: What do you mean by form fields? File input? It cannot be repopulated for security reasons.

Comment: Without code it's impossible to help.